# Pass multiple parameters to ViewComponent in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass multiple parameters to a view component in ASP.NET MVC using C#.

So I did this:

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(Ordering ordering, InvokeRequest invokeRequest)
{
    var productList = _context.GetProductForSiteService
                              .Execute(invokeRequest.ordering, invokeRequest.Searchkey, invokeRequest.page, invokeRequest.pageSize, null).Data;
     
    return View(viewName: "GetProducts", productList);
}

public class InvokeRequest
{
    public Ordering ordering { get; set; }
    public string Searchkey { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; } = 1;
    public int pageSize { get; set; } = 20;
}
```

and in the view, I have:

```
 @await Component.InvokeAsync("GetProducts", new  { Ordering=Ordering.NotOrder, Searchkey="", page=1, pageSize=20 })
```

but the value of the `InvokeRequest` in `Invoke` method is always null, how can I pass multiple parameter to a ViewComponent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties of the object you pass don't match with your `Invoke` method signature.
From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iviewcomponenthelper.invokeasync)

> An Object with properties representing arguments to be passed to the invoked view component method.

The object to pass needs the properties `ordering` and `invokeRequest`.

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("GetProducts", 
    new { 
        ordering = Ordering.NotOrder, 
        invokeRequest = new InvokeRequest { ordering = Ordering.NotOrder, Searchkey = "", page = 1, pageSize = 20 }
    })
```

---

Since that `InvokeRequest` also contains an `ordering` property, you might consider to leave that out of the components `Invoke` method signature.

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(InvokeRequest invokeRequest)
```

The call would than look like

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("GetProducts", 
    new InvokeRequest { ordering = Ordering.NotOrder, Searchkey = "", page = 1, pageSize = 20 }
    )
```